# XtraTreeList ascending and descending is sorting parent node also in 15.1

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have 2 xtra treelist as below

[image]

Now i right click on Network Component Models and click on Ascending or Descending not only the child but also parent(Network Component Models and Network Layers) get sorted however i want only child to get sorted. My code is below. **Strange is same code was working for  previous versions of Devexpress**

```
TreeList.Columns[0].SortOrder=SortOrder.Descending ;
TreeList.BeginSort();
TreeList.EndSort();
TreeList.Refresh();
```

Comment: It is not quite clear to me why you trying to resolve this issue with using the SO instead of sending direct issue-report to DevExpress support...